# Change global environment in R?

Tags: r

How to globally change R environment?

I want to use 2 environments: `TEST` and `PRODUCTION` and easly switch between them...

```
TEST <- new.env()
PRODUCTION <- new.env()
.mode <- function() {
  list(TEST = "TEST", PRODUCTION = "PRODUCTION")
}
mode <- .mode()
```

if the user want use TEST environment than he should write something like: `setGlobalRunMode(mode$TEST)`.

How to implement that `setGlobalRunMode()`?